# How to perform migrations to two databases, one for testing and one for production from a single project in EF?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, blazor-webassembly

I have a project in blazor wasm, in the appsettings.json file I have two connection strings, one points to the development database and the other to the production database, the production database is a copy of the database of development data.

appsettings. json file:

```
 "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SqlConnectionDesarrollo": "Data Source=10.0.0.41;Initial Catalog=QaInventarios;User ID=Innovacion;Password=***;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
    "SqlConnectionProduccion": "Data Source=10.0.0.41;Initial Catalog=Inventarios;User ID=Innovacion;Password=***;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
  },
```

startup file:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>
                (options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlConnectionDesarrollo")));
```

the problem is that to perform a migration what I do is comment a connection string depending on the database I want to use and changing the name in the startup, I know it's a bad practice but I don't know how to optimize this, then I execute:

```
Add-Migration NameMigration
Update-Database
```

to perform a migration, in the development database it works fine, a new migration is created and the changes are made, then I run the `Update-Database` command again to update the production database and the changes are not made and are not added the new migration and the changes are not made, the same thing happens if I delete any migration with `Remove-Migration -Force` and then an `Update-Database`

> there are inconsistencies in my database, how can I perform
> migrations, changes in both and that they remain exactly the same ??

Answer (score 1):

In EF Core 5.0, a connection string option is introduced in the EF Core CLI tool.

Example

For Development

`dotnet ef database update --connection <Development Connection string>`

And for Production.

`dotnet ef database update --connection <Production Connection string>`

Documentation about [dotnet ef update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-database-update?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002040)

Comment: It worked, but for example I create a new migration in development, I do an update-database, and I repeat the same process for my database in production, so far everything is perfect, now if for some reason that migration that I just created I delete it with remove-migration, and I perform an update-database to development, the changes are applied, then I apply an update-database to production, the changes are not applied, as I leave my two databases in the same migration state for both new migrations like the ones I remove??

Comment: Okay. That is strange. Ideally, it should be applied properly.